# How to make radio buttons linked to one-another and responsive to the status of a ControlEverything relay switch

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, radio-button, label

I am hiding the radio button and using the label as a styled push button. My issue is linking specified buttons to respond as one. If one label is clicked on I want the radio button to be checked and the related radio button to be checked therefore giving the label the appearance of a pushed down button.

```
    <script>
var baseURL = "https://api.particle.io/v1/devices/";
var accessToken = "9e8rtu0w394tup934tjpowituertw3";

        //variable name for particle call
       var method = "controlRelay";

        //RTU Relay 1
       var rtuRelay_oneID = "432p89t2u34pt92j34";
       var url_1 = baseURL + rtuRelay_oneID + "/" + method;
       //RTU Relay 2
       var rtuRelay_twoID = "13452345256435624351234";
       var url_2 = baseURL + rtuRelay_twoID + "/" + method;
       //RTU Relay 3
       var rtuRelay_threeID = "123941p23iu4p1i2jo123134";
       var url_3 = baseURL + rtuRelay_threeID + "/" + method;

//RTU_1 On
function rtuoneOn() {

singleRelay210025_On();

}     

//RTU_1 Off
function rtuoneOff() {

singleRelay210025_Off();

}

//RTU_2 On
function rtutwoOn() {

singleRelay3e002_On();

}

//RTU_2 Off
function rtutwoOff() {

singleRelay3e002_Off();

}

//RTU_3 On
function rtuthreeOn() {

singleRelay21003_On();

}

//RTU_3 Off
function rtuthreeOff() {

singleRelay21003_Off();

}

//Turning ON all RTUs
function allrtuOn() {

rtuoneOn();
rtutwoOn();
rtuthreeOn();

}

//Turning OFF all RTUs
function allrtuOff() {

rtuoneOff();
rtutwoOff();
rtuthreeOff();

}   

//Single relay unit 210025 - ON 
function singleRelay210025_On() {

$.post(url_1,
   {

   access_token: accessToken,
             params: "turnonallrelays" })

}

//Single relay unit 210025 - OFF  
function singleRelay210025_Off() {

$.post(url_1,
   {

   access_token: accessToken,
             params: "turnoffallrelays" })

}
[enter image description here][1]

//Single relay unit 3e002 - ON
function singleRelay3e002_On() {

$.post(url_2,
   {

   access_token: accessToken,
             params: "turnonallrelays" })

}

//Single relay unit 3e002 - OFF
function singleRelay3e002_Off() {

$.post(url_2,
   {

   access_token: accessToken,
             params: "turnoffallrelays" })

}

//Single relay unit 21003 - ON
function singleRelay21003_On() {

$.post(url_3,
   {

   access_token: accessToken,
             params: "turnonallrelays" })

}

//Single relay unit 21003 - OFF
function singleRelay21003_Off() {

$.post(url_3,
   {

   access_token: accessToken,
             params: "turnoffallrelays" })

}
</script>


<fieldset>
        <h4>Roof Top Units</h4>
        <!-- RTU 1 -->
        <fieldset>
        <h5>RTU 1</h5>
        <form>
        <input type='radio' id='radio0-1' onclick="rtuoneOn()" name='radio'>
        <label for='radio0-1'> On</label>
        <input type='radio' id='radio0-2' onclick="rtuoneOff()" name='radio'>
        <label for='radio0-2'> Off</label>
        </form>
        </fieldset>
        <!-- RTU 2 -->
        <fieldset>
        <h5>RTU 2</h5>
        <form> 
        <input type='radio' id='radio00-1' onclick="rtutwoOn()" name='radio'>
        <label for='radio00-1'> On</label>
        <input type='radio' id='radio00-2' onclick="rtutwoOff()" name='radio'>
        <label for='radio00-2'> Off</label>
        </form>       
        </fieldset>    
        <!-- RTU 3 -->
        <fieldset>
        <h5>RTU 3</h5>
        <form> 
        <input type='radio' id='radio000-1' onclick="rtuthreeOn()" name='radio'>
        <label for='radio000-1'> On</label>
        <input type='radio' id='radio000-2' onclick="rtuthreeOff()" name='radio'>
        <label for='radio000-2'> Off</label>
        </form>       
        </fieldset>
    </fieldset> 


        <!-- RTU Relays -->
    <fieldset>
        <h4>RTU Command Box Relays</h4>
        <!-- RTU 1 single Relay 1 -->
        <fieldset>
        <h5>Relay 1</h5>
        <form> 
        <input type='radio' id='radio0-1' onclick="singleRelay210025_On()" name='radio'>
        <label for='radio0-1'> On</label>
        <input type='radio' id='radio0-2' onclick="singleRelay210025_Off()" name='radio'>
        <label for='radio0-2'> Off</label>
        </form>       
        </fieldset>
        <!-- RTU 2 single Relay 2 -->
        <fieldset>
        <h5>Relay 2</h5>
        <form> 
        <input type='radio' id='radio00-1' onclick="singleRelay3e002_On()" name='radio'>
        <label for='radio00-1'> On</label>
        <input type='radio' id='radio00-2' onclick="singleRelay3e002_Off()" name='radio'>
        <label for='radio00-2'> Off</label>
        </form>       
        </fieldset>
        <!-- RTU 3 single Relay 3 -->
        <fieldset>
        <h5>Relay 3</h5>
        <form> 
        <input type='radio' id='radio000-1' onclick="singleRelay21003_On()" name='radio'>
        <label for='radio000-1'> On</label>
        <input type='radio' id='radio000-2' onclick="singleRelay21003_Off()" name='radio'>
        <label for='radio000-2'> Off</label>
        </form>       
        </fieldset>
    </fieldset>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried finding a solution already posted?

Comment: Yes I have: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982993/html-radio-buttons-allowing-multiple-selections https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895331/how-to-check-multiple-radio-button-radio-buttons-having-same-name http://jsfiddle.net/6jquM/2/

Comment: Okay, so why not use those answers?

Comment: I just can't figure it out with those solutions. I am getting closer though: https://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyAppleSeed/8dxtqdkc/#&togetherjs=sr6CEKNikQ