# Selected multiple radio buttons when condition is met

Tags: javascript

So I have this selection list with radio buttons that looks like this:
[image: selection list]

What I try to do is when 'AT' is selected I Want to be able to select 1 more option.
for example if 'AT' is checked I also want to be able to check 'Herstart'.
so this condition only needs to happen when 'AT' is selected.

this is a picture of the console on how the radio buttons are build :
[image: radio build]

I was thinking on something like `if(data-status =="AT"){ allow to check one more radio button}`
but here I am stuck on what to write in the if block.

this is also not my code so it's even harder to come with a solution.

anyone can point me in the right direction ?

kind regards

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895331/how-to-check-multiple-radio-button-radio-buttons-having-same-name

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor. Please show CODE not PICTURES of code

Comment: Also a radio set is defined as something where only one thing with the same name can be checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't select multiple radio buttons, to select multiple we use checkboxes, learn here the difference between checkbox and radio [more](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/radio-button-vs-checkbox-in-html/)

here is the working with checkbox:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.checked').on('change', function() {
    var x = $("#check3").is(':checked');
    if (x) {
      $('#check1').prop('checked', (x));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" class="checked" id="check1">hertstart
<input type="checkbox" class="checked" id="check2">uti,nsa
<input type="checkbox" class="checked" id="check3">AT
```

Answer (score 1):

Radio buttons are meant to be single choice *only*. If you need to have more than one option available, use checkboxes. These you can toggle active/disabled with the disabled property and javascript.